# Why don't the configuration values in my appsettings.json file map to my custom POCO object's fields via Configuration.GetSection().Get<MyObject>?

Tags: c#, .net, configuration, .net-core

I have some appsettings.json config file:

```
{
  "PocoSettings": {
    "ValueOne": "Foo",
    "ValueTwo": "Bar"
  }
}
```

and a settings object that it should populate:

```
public class PocoSettings
{
    public string ValueOne;
    public string ValueTwo;
}
```

I try to populate it in my Startup.cs file:

```
public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
        .AddEnvironmentVariables();
    this.Configuration = builder.Build();
}
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    var MySettings = this.Configuration.GetSection("PocoSettings").Get<PocoSettings>();

    // Inject MySettings into your DI container of choice here.
}
```

The `MySettings` object is created, but the values are not populated. `ValueOne` and `ValueTwo` are both null. Why?

Answer (score 7):

The Configuration extensions *require* explicit public getters and setters. If they are implicit, or if either the get or set is private then the POCO object will not be mapped. The class should read:

```
public class PocoSettings
{
    public string ValueOne { get; set; }
    public string ValueTwo { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: There is no *implicit* and *explicit* getters or setters. There are only *properties* and *fields*.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
PocoSettings MySettings = this.Configuration.Get<PocoSettings>();
```

I test it using the follow ConfigurationBuilder and my SectionsCollection class.

```
var baseConfig = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .AddJsonFile("mySettings.json")
        .Build();
SectionsCollection sectionsCollection = baseConfig.Get<SectionsCollection>();
```